# How can I make Spacing in BoxLayout?

Tags: python, kivy

I try to build a simple layout of widgets.
The BoxLayout includes three widgets: label and two anchorlayouts.
BoxLayout has a spacing parameter that is specified as "vertical".
So ... I don't see any spaces between the widgets inside the boxlayout.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYNoM.png)

There is kv:

```
<WellcomeScreen>:
    wellcome_label: wellcome_user

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.parent.pos
        size: self.parent.size
        padding: [30, 30]
        spacing: [10,10]
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                source: 'Data\game background.png'
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size

        ShadowLabel:
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .5,1,.7,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            size_hint: (1, .6)
            id: wellcome_user
            font_size: self.height/16
            text_size: self.width-10, None
            markup: True
            color: 'purple'
            halign: "center"

        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint: (1,.1)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,.5,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            Button:
                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
                size_hint: (None,None)
                size: (self.parent.height-5,self.parent.height-5)
                background_normal: "Data\Button_sound.png"

        AnchorLayout:
            size_hint: (1,.3)
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: .2,.7,.7,1
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size

            Button:
                canvas.before:
                    Rectangle:
                        source: "Data\Button_start.png"
                        pos: self.pos
                        size: self.size

                pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5,"center_y":0.5}
                size_hint: (None, None)
                size: (self.parent.height/4*3, self.parent.height/4*3)
                background_color: (1,1,1,0)
                font_size: self.height/4
                text_size: self.width, None
                text: "START"
                color: "yellow"
                bold: True
                halign: 'center'
                on_press:
                    root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                    root.manager.current = 'login'
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html#kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout.spacing), the `spacing` is a number, not a list of numbers. Try changing:

```
spacing: [10,10]
```

to:

```
spacing: 10
```